# How to fix "Powershell needs Windows management system 4.0'

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, command-line

I want to know
How i install Powershell in my win 10 pc because it dont came installed in it

[image: WinRm error]

Please help me. I will be very thankful to you

Comment: Which edition of Windows are you using? Pro/Enterprise ships with Windows Management Framework 5.1, and I sort of expected Home to do too... Try installing from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616

Comment: Now i am getting error.
Windows cannot open this type of file (.msu).

Now what i do